# eBay to magento integration

Tags: magento-1.8, import, export, module

I have integrated magento products to eBay using M2E pro but now we have to integrated eBay product in to magento(reverse process). Is there any way to do this.

Comment: Its look like you are looking for module which can import products from  eBay to magento store. Yes, it is possible to import products from eBay to magento with the help of module "ebay2magento" from magegaga.com

Answer (score 2):

This is possible via numerous methods.

The first is to use eBay FileExchange to make an export from eBay and then use that as an import for Magento (Magmi is suggested). http://pages.ebay.co.uk/file_exchange/

You could download the live eBay listings in eBay's TurboLister and then export to a CSV file. http://pages.ebay.co.uk/turbo_lister/

And there are 3 extensions in Magento connect for this task (all quite expensive, just search for "eBay") and some can import directly into Magento.

Or you could hook up to the eBay API and download them programmatically.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Is that the right way around @Pramod?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible. I had to do this a few months ago, but had to scrape products from eBay and import to Magento.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement an automated integration, you will need to write an extension in Magento that uses [eBay's API](http://developer.ebay.com/common/api/).

Your Magento extension retrieves product data from eBay using this on a regular basis (cron jobs), and it will create or update products on your Magento installation. eBay seems to have pretty decent documentation for third-party developers, so give it a shot.